# A Button needs to be clicked twice to close a Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, revit-api, dialogresult

I am trying to run a simple code. I have created a Form with a ComboBox (`DropDownStyle = DropDown`), which is empty in the beginning, it's filled with two when the DropDown is opened.
This Form also has 2 Buttons, one of them is the `proceedButton` Button sown in code.

In this block of code I am checking if the ComboBox is empty and if it, I am prompting user to select an Item from the ComboBox.
When the item is selected, I want to click `proceedButton` and the Form should close, but it this action takes a second click.

```
private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    exitButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    Debug.WriteLine("Cancel was clicked");
    Close();
}

private void proceedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing was selected, please try again!");
    }
    else
    {
        proceedButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Debug.WriteLine("Proceed was clicked");
    }
}
```

Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button Controls have a [DialogResult property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult) you can set to one of the [DialogResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult) values.

- Clicking a Button that has its `DialogResult` property set to a value that is not  `DialogResult.None`, causes the Dialog to Close, also setting the value returned by `Form.ShowDialog()`:

  ```
  DialogResult result = Form.ShowDialog().
  ```

The `DialogResult` property of Buttons is usually set in the Designer or in the Form Constructor (same thing).

- When a Button with `DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel` is clicked, the Dialog is closed. The same value is returned by `Form.ShowDiaog()`.
- The same applies to a Button with `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`.

So, set these properties in the Designer, remove `Close()` from the `exitButton` Button `Click` handler (this action is already performed automatically).

- You need to click `OK` twice because the first click just sets the `DialogResult` property, which is then acknowledged and performs its default action only in the second click.

In the error condition of the `proceedButton` Button `Click` handler, set `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;` to cancel the action, before you show the MessageBox.

The code can then be changed in:

```
private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Cancel was clicked");
}

private void proceedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text)) {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing was selected, please try again!");
    }
    else {
        Debug.WriteLine("Proceed was clicked");
    }
}
```